# Computing the Legendre symbol $6 \choose 11 $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Compute the Legendre symbol $6 \choose 11$

By euler's critetion, ${6 \choose 11}=-1$, but ${6 \choose 11}={3 \choose 11 }{2\choose 11}=-1*-1=1$.

I am confused about that result.

Comment: $\binom{3}{11}=1$.

Comment: right, thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

$\left(\frac{3}{11}\right)$ is $1$, not $-1$, since $5^2=3$ mod $11$.